# Passing the data in Post request from HTML page to Python application

Tags: python, nginx

I'm newbie to the Web server.
Have installed Nginx on Raspberry Pi 2 and its working. Also have added a default HTML page with a text box, and I can access the page over the local Network. 
My question is, is there a way to pass the text in the textbox to a python application running on raspberry Pi when user posts the text?

I can also install CherryPy if there is a easy way to do it in CherryPy.

Comment: You should look into [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (simple, lightweight) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (less simple). There's a fair bit of work that goes into translating HTTP POST requests from the web server into objects that are consumable in Python.

Comment: Yes, you just need to create a form with your form inside and define the action as being POST. On the server side you need a do_POST() that will receive the form. As @ScottHarris mentioned, you can use Flask or Django which are web framework that makes it easier. Or even more simpler: BaseHTTPServer You can check an example of mine here: https://github.com/HugoSPT/tinyurl/blob/master/tinyurl.py

Comment: @HugoSousa , thanks baseHTTPServer looks the way to go ahead for my scenario.